# How that works ! (template<std::size_t Size>)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

template<std::size_t Size>
void Print(std::array<int, Size>& arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        println(arr[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Print(arr);
}
```

How does the size got passed to the function template without defining it like `Print<5>(arr)` ? (at line 7 "the actual template", at line 16 "calling the function")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the size got passed to the function template without defining it like `Print<5>(arr)` ?

It is thanks to *template argument deduction*. The size is deduced from the call `Print(arr)`. `Print()` is a function template with a *non-type template parameter* (i.e., `Size`) of type `std::size_t`:

```
template<std::size_t Size>
void Print(std::array<int, Size>&);
```

That is, the template parameter `Size` is deduced to a value of type `std::size_t`, which corresponds to the second template argument of the `std::array` passed as a function argument when calling `Print()`.

Comment: Thx for that :) !

Answer (score 0):

That’s called “template argument deduction” where it can figure it out based on what you’re passing in.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction